# How do you replace data from a TextView instead of adding to the TextView from a firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, foreach, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I'm populating a Textview from a firebase database. When I add an extra child (`names`) to the database, the TextView keeps the previous data and repeats the previous data plus the new child entry. I want to dismiss the previous data and just have the the updated version. For example the TextView populates with

```
Mary, John
```

But when I add an extra child the TextView populates with

```
Mary, John, Mary, John, Adam
```

I just want the TextView to populate With `Mary, John, Adam`

here is my code

```
TextView stringTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   stringTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("County").child("Dublin").child("contacts");

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
               // Log.d("TAG", name);
                names.add(name);
                //String number = ds.child("number").getValue(String.class);
                //Log.d("Name", name + " / " + number);
            }
            for (String name : names) {
                //stringTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                stringTextView.setText(stringTextView.getText().toString() + name + " , ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };

    ref.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    **stringTextview.setText(" ")**
```

That's what I'd do, change the text to empty every time I capture a new snapshot of data :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I helped.